# finding a label and value within lines of text with spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I created a script just using basic Python that searches for fields in a document and matches the fields to a value.

I want to know if spacy can do this sort of thing.

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447810/spacy-nlp-regex-how-can-i-add-custom-entities-and-labels-using-regex-in-spacy) in that I can use regex to find the values, but I have multiple fields i want to search for.

I have been reading about the [PhraseMatcher](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher) which seems to be able to find the fields, but cannot seem to find a way to then find corresponding values once the fields have been located.

The reason I am doing this: my solution works but I feel that it is not very sophisticated, and that there may be better approaches out there.

Is this a valid use case for spacy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Spacy Entity Recognizer](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer), it was created for this kind of purposes. 
This is more appropriate than regular expressions.

Now, it depends on the complexity of your named entities, if they are really very regular and have the same pattern you may use regex. But on my opinion, the entity recognizer is better.